# How to prevent Dos Attack in Async Sessionless Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I have an async controller which works under sessionless state in my Asp MVC App to handle concurrent long live requests. Every thing is working fine, but I just realized that **if some one make continuous request to my async sessionless controller as Dos attack, my app might go to the hell,lol...**
Do you know anyway to prevent Dos attack like that in an async sessioness controller in asp.net mvc ?? I did search arround with google but still don't get good solution yet. I really need your advise right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it.

A DOS attack typically overloads hardware and not software.  Your code won't be the one to blame.

Comment: It must be effect to your web application first before down to overload hardware, don't you think so ?

Comment: @DucN - This stuff is googlable...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack

Answer (score 0):

Async controllers or not if your application gets a DDOS attack you are pretty screwed.